# Podcasts on Hompods with Siri

Tags: podcasts.app, homepod

I use Apple podcasts with Homepods. iOs 15

I can ask Siri "Play podcast X" It then plays the lasted unlistened podcast from the series X.

However it does not mark it as played so when next time I ask Siri to "Play podcast X" it plays the same podcast.

If I listen to the podcast from my iPad or just mark it as listened to then on the Homepod it will play the unlistened episode

How do I get Hopepod to mark the episode as played?

Comment: can you try to ask Siri "Continue podcast X" to see if it works ?

Comment: @tama - Its got worse it now will only play Apple Podcasts and play the last podcast of any series not the series that was asked for.